# query rows left join does not match ansi join equivalence rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

good evening,

I have 2 queries that return different row values, one with left join syntax and the other with old ansi

syntax that I need to create a materialized view in oracle. I need to add in the old syntax value1 (+) to

match the first left join query (which includes the nulls).
Thanks a lot.

**Observation**: the error occurs because the table "detalle_ordenes" has a value that does not exist in the table "tabla_hija". but I
want to show all rows without filtering it like in left Join query

```
select  --(query number 1, returns 18 records.)
       o.rowid o_rowid,
       c.rowid c_rowid,
       e.rowid e_rowid,
       f.rowid f_rowid,
       ordenid,
      o.detalleid,
      o.productoid,
       f.vdescricion as v2descripcion
    from detalle_ordenes o
    left join tabla_hija c on o.estado=c.vvalor and c.tipo_filtro=1 
    left join tabla_hija e on o.segmento=e.vvalor and e.tipo_filtro=2
    left join tabla_hija f on o.column1=f.vvalor and f.tipo_filtro=3

select --(query number 2, returns 15 records.)
   o.rowid o_rowid,
   c.rowid c_rowid,
   e.rowid e_rowid,
   f.rowid f_rowid,
   ordenid,
   o.detalleid,
   o.productoid,
   f.vdescricion as v2descripcion
from detalle_ordenes o, tabla_hija c, tabla_hija e,tabla_hija f
where
   ( o.estado=c.vvalor(+) and c.tipo_filtro=1 )
   and
   ( o.segmento=e.vvalor(+) and e.tipo_filtro=2) 
   and 
   ( o.column1=f.vvalor(+) and f.tipo_filtro=3)
```

Comment: Add the (+) operator to **all** column references from the outer joined tables, even when compared to constants.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that this is the solution. I will prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `(+)` to all the conditions in the outer join filters:

```sql
select *
from   detalle_ordenes o,
       tabla_hija c,
       tabla_hija e,
       tabla_hija f
WHERE  o.estado   = c.vvalor (+)
AND    1          = c.tipo_filtro (+) 
AND    o.segmento = e.vvalor (+)
AND    2          = e.tipo_filtro (+) 
AND    o.column1  = f.vvalor (+)
AND    3          = f.tipo_filtro (+)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5a73ee109a38c8cae8916c135483e5b2)*